# Entering number with leading decimal in angular input type="number"

Tags: angularjs

Please reference [this jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NEhG9/3/)

Chrome and Safari allow you to input numbers with leading decimals.

IE9 (haven't tested 10+), and Firefox will not let you enter the decimal point.  The only way to enter such a number is to prefix it with "0." or to enter the number, then go back and enter the decimal point.

This doesn't occur if the input is not bound to an ng-model.

Obviously, the Chrome/Safari behavior is desired.

Work arounds include using a type="text" with Regex or writing a custom directive (that would probably do the same thing).

Code below is a preliminary example....the fiddle contains a more complete demo

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<input type="number" ng-model="Value" />
    {{Value}}
</div>

var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
});
```

Is this an angular bug and/or is there a known workaround?

Comment: I was able to enter .5 into both boxes. I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: What browser were you using?

Comment: Sorry, re-reading and see the correct behavior is in Chrome (I originally thought the opposite).

Comment: This is an angular bug. See progress here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/5682